# Vocabulary Comprehension:Odd Word Out

Tags: vocabulary

Would you please tell me which word does not belong to this group of words?

> Progressive,,
>   Traditional,
>   Timid,
>   Cautious.

Comment: I don't see any clear triplet there, three words from the same semantic field. I would consider it a flawed question.  **timid** is probably the best word to eliminate, in that it is a personal characteristic with somewhat pejorative connotations, and the others have no pejorative connotations.

Comment: Only one is about moving forwards - to boldly go, etc.

Comment: "Traditional " is the only quality that doesn't change.

Comment: @TRomano If you are progressive, you like trying bold new things. If you are any of the others, you don't.

Comment: @Araucaria: The politically cautious person sits between the progressive and the traditionalist. You are cautious when trying something new, right? No need for caution when doing the same old thing.

Answer (score 2):

Because this is a *vocabulary comprehension* exercise, the answer is probably based on the meaning of the words. The "odd word out" is therefore most likely ***progressive***.

Although they are not really synonyms of one another, *traditional*, *timid*, and *cautious* are all commonly given as synonyms for **conservative**, which is a clear antonym of *progressive*.

See, for example, the definition and first ten suggestions in *Thesaurus.com* (sorted by relevance):

> Synonyms for [conservative](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/conservative?s=t)
>   *adj* **cautious**, moderate, tending to
>   preserve the status quo
>
> - middle-of-the-road
> - reactionary
> - **timid**
> - **traditional**
> - bourgeois
> - constant
> - firm
> - fuddy-duddy
> - quiet
> - redneck
>     ...

Comment: Besides, conservative may also be reactionary and thus, regressive, which is a 100 percent antonym of progressive, the odd word. Mine was a really silly guess.

Comment: @Rompey I liked your idea from a riddling perspective—it would be a good "lateral thinking" answer on the Puzzling SE, I think.

Answer (score 0):

"Traditional" can't describe  a person's character  All the other adjectives can:

> He is a progressive politician. He is a timid boy. He is a cautious person.

"Traditional " also means "doesn't change ". The others change, slightly, but change.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't agree. *Traditional* can easily be used to describe people. The odd one out is *progressive*, imo. The others all have a sense of conservatism.